# Is it possible to express the jacobi derivative of position with respect to angular displacement easier?

Tags: vector-analysis, matrix-calculus

Let

$$ \vec{\omega} = \frac{\vec{s} \times \vec{v}}{\left\lvert s\right\rvert^2} $$

and define

$$ \vec{\theta} = \int \vec{\omega} \,\mathrm{d} t $$
$$ R = \frac{\mathrm{d} \vec{s}}{\mathrm{d} \vec{\theta}} $$
$$ D = \frac{\mathrm{d} \vec{\theta}}{\mathrm{d} \vec{s}} $$

I think one can obtain the relations:

$$  \vec{v} = R \vec{\omega} $$

and

$$  D \vec{v} = \vec{\omega} $$

but how does one solve for $R$ and $D$ themselves?

I'm also not sure about the meaning of the two and when each one is well defined.

Answer (score 1):

Notice from your first equation that $w$ is perpendicular to $v$, so $$w\cdot v=0$$

Define a new vector that is perpendicular to both $w$ and $v$ $$b=w\times v$$

Use the "BAC-CAB" rule evaluate the cross product
$$\eqalign{
b\times w &= (w\times v)\times w \cr
 &= w^2v - (w\cdot v)w \cr
 &= w^2v \cr
}$$
Now use the Levi-Civita tensor to define the cross-matrix for $b$ 
$$\eqalign{
 B &= -\varepsilon\cdot b \cr
 Bw &= b\times w  &= w^2v \cr
 \Big(\frac{B}{w^2}\Big)w &= v \cr\cr
}$$
So we have found an expression for the $R$ matrix
$$R=\frac{B}{w^2}$$
This result can be simplified to
$$\eqalign{R=\frac{vw^T-wv^T}{w^Tw}\cr\cr}$$
It is worth noting that $R$ is singular, so you won't get anywhere with an approach based on $R^{-1}$.

Comment: Yeah, I'm confused about the singularity issue. I'm not sure exactly about the difference between $\frac{\mathrm{d} \vec{\theta}}{\mathrm{d} \vec{s}}$ and $\frac{\mathrm{d} \vec{s}}{\mathrm{d} \vec{\theta}}$ and which is better.

Comment: If you play this same game with $D$ you get $$\eqalign{D&=\frac{wv^T-vw^T}{v^Tv}\cr\cr RD&=\frac{ww^T}{w^Tw}+\frac{vv^T}{v^Tv} &=I-\frac{bb^T}{b^Tb}\cr}$$So $R$ and $D$ are not quite inverses of each other.

Answer (score 0):

From $\vec{v} = R\vec{\omega}$

$$ D \vec{v} = \frac{\vec{s} \times \vec{v}}{\left\lvert s\right\rvert^2} $$

$$ D \hat{e}_k = \frac{\vec{s} \times \hat{e}_k}{\left\lvert s\right\rvert^2} $$

$R$ is then the inverse of that but I'm not sure it is always valid to take the inverse.